# Spring JPA, secondary table for multiple language

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

With Spring JPA on Hibernate 5, I am trying to design data model for product catalog that supports multiple languages.

The design of database tables is like this. I will have 2 tables to keep information of `Product` entity.

### products

```
-------------------------------
product_id |   price   | stock
-------------------------------
         1      100.0     10
         2      50.0      10
         3      99.0      10
```

### product_details

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
product_id |            name              |                       description                | language_code
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1              IPhone X                 A good mobile phone by Apple                       en
         1              ไอโฟน X                 โทรศัพท์มือถือคุณภาพจาก Apple                          th
         2              Galaxy X                 A good mobile phone by Samsung                     en
         2              กาแล็กซี่ X                 โทรศัพท์มือถือคุณภาพจาก Samsung                       th
         3              Nexus X                  A good mobile phone by Google                      en
         3              เน็กซัส X                  โทรศัพท์มือถือคุณภาพจาก Google                        th
```

The relation is **one product can have details in multiple languages**. In the example data, each of 3 products has details in 2 languages, **en** for English, **th** for Thai.

When a language code is defined, the relation between these 2 tables is one-to-one. I want to map these 2 tables into a single class `Product`. Retrieving a product from the repository will always has language code specified.

```
interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    Optional<Product> findByProductIdAndLanguageCode(Long productId, String languageCode);
}
```

JPA has `@SecondaryTable` annotation that can map 2 tables into one entity class when the 2 tables have one-to-one relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
@SecondaryTable(name="product_details")
class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private Long productId;

    @Column(name="price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name="stock")
    private Integer stock;

    @Column(name="name", table="product_details")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description", table="product_details")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="language_code", table="product_details")
    private String languageCode;
}
```

But in my case, the 2 tables are not typical one-to-one. How can I tell hibernate that the language code will always be specified, by which it will always get 1 row from `product_details` for a product?

Comment: This is most probably not doable in JPA, unless you are willing to add the language code to the identifier. Even so, I am not sure if JPA supports a composite id split into separate tables.

Comment: According to the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_table_joins) it is supported by TopLink and EclipseLink.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I want to do exactly the same.

Comment: @Puma I did not find the direct solution. What I have done is to join the `@OneToMany ProductDetails pd` in the `Product` class and then create getter method for each relevant field such as `public String getName() { // find pd where languageCode = currentLanguageCode, then return pd.name}`